# UITableView incorrect offset after .reloadSections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have next code when I tap to show / hide content.

```
func showHideAssets() {
     isOpenHiddenAssets = !isOpenHiddenAssets

     tableView.beginUpdates()
     tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .fade)
     tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

When first section contain many items, after reloading sections table scrolling to bottom with incorrect offset

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if section == 0 {
          return 10
     }
     return isOpenHiddenAssets ? assetsHiddenItems.count : 0
}
```

Video where first section have 3 items. It works well
[video 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rrfprrvbrwp60c0/video1.mov?dl=0)

Video where first section have 10 items. It have bug.[video 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j29te5sql09ltvv/video2.mov?dl=0)

Comment: try `tableView.reloadData()` after reloading section

Comment: This don't help

Comment: Maybe try implement : ```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat``` . Try with a value like 80.0 (doesn't really matter)

Comment: It helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution is replacing

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: In my case it work in collapsible table with just adding `estimatedHeightForRowAt` which return not the same (i.e. even if return +1) result as `heightForRowAt` returns